# /proc/diskstats: No such file or directory

Tags: performance, monitoring, drive, statistics, proc

Trying to get some disk performance metrics (in particular, using munin), found that  `/proc/diskstats` does not exist.

Tried `yum provides '*/diskstats'` but nothing except munin was found.

CentOS release 6.7 (Final)

```
uname -a
Linux domain.com 2.6.32-042stab112.15 #1 SMP Tue Oct 20 17:22:56 MSK 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

So, how can I fix it?

Comment: That looks like a Virtuozzo environment and you'd need to contact your hosting provider to enable that for you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looks like you are on a Virtual server (VPS). If your VPS is based on OpenVZ, openVZ usually doesn't expose all counters (like /proc/diskstats) to its containers.